# Analyze rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am wondering if there is a tool that will tell how many lines of code are present in my Rails app, what are controllers and models present as well?

Comment: partial answer to your question: `rake stats` :) have a try on your console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `rake stats`. It's built into Rails.

Comment: hah. thanks. seriously, a google would have done. But i guess i didnt use the right keywords there. Thanks :)

Comment: need to wait 6 mins :) . i will.